# How can I retrieve the current user from a DataExtender?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I've written a DataExtender that 'hides' certain items from view. The idea is that some items should not be visible in any list in the GUI, even though the user may have access to it (similar to system files/folders in windows, which are not normally visible even though you are entitled to read them).

It's working fine, but now I want to make an exception for system administrators: they should always see every item. But I can't see how I can retrieve the current user from within my DataExtender. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: I have mixed feelings about hiding items... what if the Editor creates an item with the same name - they'll get a conflict warning message, but will not understand why...

Comment: I totally agree. I have a very specific reason for this: I need to hide the Audience Management node from view for certain users. That way I can let them manage contacts that are filtered through a distribution list, without letting them see all contacts in the address book. The conflict you're describing couldn't occur in this case because it's not possible to create anything at that level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Utils.GetUserName()` to get the Windows username and then create your own Core Service client, call Impersonate, and then call GetCurrentUser.